# Determining optimal inheritance graph

Tags: inheritance

I have a list of multiple (~40) business objects which all share some properties, either with the whole set or subsets. This could be described with the following pseudo-code:

```
Object Foo
  property a
  property b

Object Bar
  property a
  property c

Object Baz
  property b
  property c
```

In my case there are about 20 different properties.

How do I create the optimal inheritance graph, i.e. the one that results in the fewest (abstract) parent classes, assuming behavior is not different, only the properties?

Comment: That's not the way to go about class design. You should aim for clarity and ease of extension, not brevity.

Comment: @skaffman I would generally agree with you. However, faced with the high number of seemingly unrelated business objects (and assuming, blindly, that the number will not increase) I am looking for a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an article proposing a formal solution to my problem: [A formal method for inheritance graph hierarchy construction](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=603511). However, I am unable to access it.